# What is the purpose of the "finally" element in ant-contrib's trycatch?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I know this task is supposed to mimic the structure of try/catch in traditional programming languages, but I can't for the life of me come up with a scenario where `<finally>` would actually be useful in an Ant script.

For example:

```
<trycatch>
  <try>
    <copy file="foo.txt" todir="bar" />
  </try>
  <catch>
    <echo message="could not copy" />
  </catch>
  <finally>
    <echo message="all done" />
  </finally>
</trycatch>
```

...would be functionally identical to:

```
<trycatch>
  <try>
    <copy file="foo.txt" todir="bar" />
  </try>
  <catch>
    <echo message="could not copy" />
  </catch>
</trycatch>
<echo message="all done" />
```

The Ant engine will always move to the next line after the trycatch block after it completes, so what's the point of including a block of code that executes at the end of it?

For reference: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first snippet, "all done" will be printed regardless of whether the `catch` block was successful.

In the second snippet, "all done" will *not* be printed if the `catch` block was unsuccessful.

Both your examples show a trivial `catch` block, containing a simple `echo`. Consider what would happen if the `catch` block contained a task that might actually fail...